# Pygame Rect center can't overwrite Rect's left

Tags: python, pygame, rect

In the code below I add a center and before it a top and a left attribute to the self.rect (this is only for learning and understanding pygame behavior). When I add the top attribute it seems that the top will be overwritten by the center, but having a left before center comes changes the x position of the block. Can any one explain why the left doesn't get overwritten by center?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


screen=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.image=pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill((0,0,200))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(top=400,center=(0,0)) 
        #this will obviously be overwritten by center, but not the following, why?
        #self.rect=self.image.get_rect(left=400,center=(0,0))

b=Block()
blockGrp=pygame.sprite.Group()
blockGrp.add(b)
print blockGrp

while 1:
    pygame.time.wait(50)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    blockGrp.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

The keywords you use when you call the `get_rect` function are, in the end, passed as a `dict` to the function.

The `Rect` class* then iterates over this `dict` and calls the appropriate setter function.

Now note that the order of the items in the `dict` is not the same order you used when creating that `dict`.

For example, try running the following code in your python interpreter:

```
>>> {"top": 400, "center": (0, 0)}
{'top': 400, 'center': (0, 0)}
>>> {"left": 400, "center": (0, 0)}
{'center': (0, 0), 'left': 400}
>>>
```

As you can see, when you use `...get_rect(left=400,center=(0,0))`, a `dict` like `{'center': (0, 0), 'left': 400}` is created (this is an implementation detail that may change depending on the python interpreter you use).

So, first `center` will be set, then `left` will be set.

Now if you use `...get_rect(top=400,center=(0,0))`, a `dict` like `{'top': 400, 'center': (0, 0)}` will be generated, and `top` will be set first, then `center` will be set.

For more information about how `dict` works internally, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479974/142637) great answer.

---

That being said, if you want to set multiple attributes that collide with each other, (like `top` and `center` e.g.), you should call the setter manually, e.g.

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(0,0)) 
self.rect.top = 400
```

---

* it's not really a `Rect` *class*, since it's implemented in C, so it's a C function that does the work in the end.